# How do I call .getJSON on an array?

Tags: javascript

I know that .getJSON makes asynchronous calls. This means I can't console.log the array 'streams', after the for loop (since the .getJSON won't have finished). However, most of my Javascript depends on the outcome of these calls! I think this is where promises come in.

But I really need to wait until all of the .getJSON calls are made through the array, which means only putting the promise call on the last piece of the array (I think). How should I go about doing this, or am I looking at this problem the wrong way? Thanks.

```
var reg_users = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
var streams = [];
for (var i = 0; i < reg_users.length; i++) {
  $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + reg_users[i] + '?callback=?', function(data) {
    streams.push(data);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var reg_users = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
var reqs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < reg_users.length; i++) {
  reqs.push($.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + reg_users[i] + '?callback=?'));
}

Promise.all(reqs).then((res) => {
  // do things with responses here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution.

```
var reg_users = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
var streams = [];
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < reg_users.length; i++) {
  promises.push($.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + reg_users[i] + '?callback=?'));
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function(all_data){
  // all_data is a list of response
  all_data.forEach(function(data){ 
    streams.push(data);
  });
});
```